# Finding a chart around a point in a submanifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Define the set $M:= \{ x \in \mathbb R^4 : x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 =1 \}$, so $M$ is a 3-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$.

I want to find a chart around $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \in M$, but I don't have an idea how to start constructing and would be glad for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $f := x_1x_4 - x_2x_3  - 1$. For all $x \in M$ we have $grad (f)(x) \neq 0$, hence M is a manifold. Consider a point $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \in M$, without loss of generality $a_1 \neq 0$. You get coordinate functions $$(x_1, x_2, x_3)$$

defined on the open subset $U_1:=\{x \in M: x_1 \neq 0\} \subset M$.

**Note**. On $U_1$ one has $x_4 = \frac {1+x_2 x_3}{x_1}$.

Comment: Sorry, if this is stupid to ask, but how do I go on from this?

Comment: @xxx You asked for a chart $(U_1, (z_1, z_2, z_3))$ around a given point of $M$. What do you want to do now with this chart, what is the context of your original question?

Comment: Uh, I just mixed up things, thanks for your help!